# El trigger no actualiza a las personas de proyecto, solo al nuevo trabajador que inserto nuevo

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-8.0

Tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio:

> Hacer un trigger que cada vez que se incorpore un registro en trabaja_en, compruebe si hay menos de 4 empleados trabajando en este proyectos. Si es así se debe aumentar en 100€ el sueldo de todos los empleados de este proyecto incluido el nuevo.

### Tengo la siguiente estructura de base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para realizar este ejercicio había pensado en separarlo por partes. Es decir antes de de realizar el trigger realice una función la cual cuenta el numero de empleado que trabaja en ese proyecto, el cual creo que me da correcto, porque lo he estado comprobando.

***Mi función:***

```
USE empresa;
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS codArt $$
CREATE FUNCTION codArt(dniE VARCHAR(9), numProyect INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT count(num_proyec) INTO contador FROM empleados,trabaja_en WHERE dni=dni_empleado 
    AND num_proyec=numProyect;
    RETURN contador;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***Mi trigger:***

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS dirPrecio $$
CREATE trigger dirPrecio BEFORE INSERT on trabaja_en
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (codArt(NEW.dni_empleado,NEW.num_proyec)<4) THEN
        UPDATE empleados SET sueldo=sueldo+100 WHERE dni=NEW.dni_empleado;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Trigger y Funcion</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/322)

***Por ejemplo:*** Si inserto lo siguiente.

```
INSERT INTO trabaja_en VALUES('123456789',3,40.0);
```

La tabla *empleado* debe cambiar el sueldo y sumarle 100 extra al sueldo de:

> Jose Perez Perez a 30100

> Fernando Ojeda Ordonez 38100

> Alberto Campos Sastres 40100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi error es que el update me faltaba añadir la tabla proyecto para poder comprobar correctamente el numero de proyecto

***La función no la he tocado :***

```
USE empresa;
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS codArt $$
CREATE FUNCTION codArt(dniE VARCHAR(9), numProyect INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE contador INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT count(num_proyec) INTO contador FROM empleados,trabaja_en WHERE dni=dni_empleado AND num_proyec=numProyect;
    RETURN contador;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***Y el trigger es lo que cambia :***

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS dirPrecio $$
CREATE trigger dirPrecio BEFORE INSERT on trabaja_en
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (codArt(NEW.dni_empleado,NEW.num_proyec)<4) THEN
        UPDATE empleados,proyecto SET sueldo=sueldo+100 WHERE dpto=cod_dpto AND num_proyec=NEW.num_proyec;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

***La linea que cambia es :***

```
UPDATE empleados,proyecto SET sueldo=sueldo+100 WHERE dpto=cod_dpto AND num_proyec=NEW.num_proyec;
```

Si lo ejecutáis y miráis el sueldo de los nombre que he puesto veréis como se ha actualizado el sueldo

[<kbd>Ejecutar Trigger y Funcion</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/325)

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es por qué usas el DNI para contar la cantidad de personas trabajando en un proyecto. ¿No basta con esto: `SELECT count(*) INTO contador FROM trabaja_en WHERE num_proyec=numProyect;` si usas el DNI no creo que esta condición quede satisfecha: *compruebe si hay menos de 4 empleados trabajando en este proyectos*

Comment: Si también es válido,  o si no el número de proyecto cualquiera de esos vale

Comment: Es que me suena raro ese criterio.

Comment: Se puede usar o * , el dni ya que no se repite o los números de proyectos. Por ejemplo imagínate qué quieres que cuentes los empleados pero que no se repita pues en lugar de poner ``SELECT 
DISTINCT  count(*) FROM empleados`` no te dará los repitifoz en ese caso debes de usar ``SELECT count(DISTINCT dni) FROM empleados`` y eso ya sí te contaría los distintos empleados @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Tu línea `CREATE trigger dirPrecio BEFORE INSERT on trabaja_en` indica que se ejecutará antes de un `INSERT` y no antes de un `UPDATE`.

Deberías hacer dos triggers diferentes, aunque parte del contenido común podrías hacerlo mediante un procedimiento para simplificar o por si en el futuro lo cambias y así que esté todo más homogéneo.

Saludos!

Comment: Ya pero el problema es que solo se debe usar un único trigger, el objetivo es que cuando se inserte un campo en trabaja_en en empleado se debe actualizar el sueldo automáticamente el sueldo +100 es decir que si tiene de sueldo base 20000 el empleado después de ejecutar el trigger obtendrá 20100, si te fija en el if tengo la función y dentro el update.

Comment: ya lo he solcuionado